# Windows doesn't respect default program for .txt files when opening external file from command line

Tags: windows, command-line, file-association, kubernetes

I'm currently working with a program called kubernetes. I open a file locally with the command "kubectl edit deployment/deployment-name" on my command line. This gives me a .txt file that I can then save that will be reuploaded.

When opening .txt files from my file explorer, it opens properly in my default program, VS Code, but in this instance it opens in Notepad.

Anyone have ideas how to get this to work and have the file open in the proper program?

Comment: Are you sure the problem is Windows and not, say, `kubectl` itself?

Comment: I'm not sure and I wouldn't quite know how to test this with another program. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`kubectl edit` documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#edit):

> It will open the editor defined by your KUBE_EDITOR, or EDITOR environment variables, or fall back to 'vi' for Linux or 'notepad' for Windows.

`kubectl` simply does not use file associations, a Windows UI concept. If you want to use a different editor, you need to use the environment variables described. Be aware that other cross-platform utilities may also use the `EDITOR` environment variable.

If you absolutely have to use file associations, you’ll have to find (or create) a wrapper program. I didn’t find any in a quick search.